# Laravel's Eloquent's 'with' array is breaking

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I am trying to abstract my models using a single base class. I have three models that inherit from the same base:

1. Repair
2. Inspection
3. Purchase

I am able to successfully create and persist  the models to the DB, but when fetching I get a blank screen, no errors are thrown. When I remove the `$with` attribute everything seems to work.

Heres the code:

```php
abstract class ItemType extends Model 
{
    public    $timestamps = false;
    protected $with       = ['details'];

    public function details()
    {
         return $this->morphOne(Item::class, 'type', 'item_details_type', 'item_details_id', 'id');
    }
}

class Repair extends ItemType
{
    protected $table      = 'repairs';
    protected $guarded    = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
    protected $morphClass = self::class;
}
class Inspection extends ItemType {}
class Purchase   extends ItemType {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I decided to use `morphTo` relationships without the abstract class to solve the issue.